# Tools for Optimizing Posgresql Performance

Tags: untagged

In MySQL there are tools like mysqltuner.pl and tuning-primer.sh, that can help you optimize the performance of your databases.

Is there something similar for Postgresql?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know there are no *good* scripts to automatically tune Postgresql. The defaults are pretty sane for a small installation, and it's hard to write a script that does much better guesses for large scale databases, as it is so dependant on your application.

Instead of relying on a script I would strongly recommend that you read up a bit on Postgresql tuning. Start with:

http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Performance_Optimization

http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server

Beyond the basic settings, my experience is that the most commonly overlooked factor is indexes and analysis to ensure the query planner have good data to work with.

Comment: +1 - database tuning isn't something that should be left to a script. Even the commercial DBs that have tuning applications (like MSSQL) surround them with the caveat that you should evaluate their suggestions carefully before implementing them.